# programmatically shutdown Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

write a C program for Windows xp shutdown 
(when we compile that program our system will be shutdown)

Comment: A program that shuts the system down on compilation? I want one!

Comment: @sharp do you want a pink pony with it?

Comment: If you manage to do that, your compiler must be pretty evil.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want one that exits Windows when it's *run*, you could use [`ExitWindowsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`InitiateSystemShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`shutdown`](http://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm) command.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  printf("Now shutting down...");
  system("shutdown /s");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
system("shutdown -s");
```

or if you wanna set a time

```
system("shutdown -s -t 30");
```

However, it will not shutdown on compilation, but on execution

P.S.: don't forget to include process.h

Answer (score 0):

```
system("shutdown -s -t 0");
```

Immediately shutsdown.